# Can Ghosts Interact With Each Other?

Tags: harry-potter, ghost

Can the ghosts in Harry Potter interact with each other?  I think I remember some games they played that indicated they were able to have physical contact.  Is that right?  Can they interact with each other on a physical level?  Or would they just pass through each other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Headless_Hunt_games lists 4 games from the Headless Hunt in CoS:

```
Head Hockey
Head Polo
Horseback Head-Juggling
Headless Bowling
```

While the first 3 have no details of them, sounds like to make the game work you HAVE to have inter-ghost contacts. As for Bowling, even mortals can play, presumably (it's 100% true in a computer game, but can only be inferred from a book):

> **Sir Patrick**: "So, Harry me lad, care for a little headless bowling?"
>   **Harry**: "I'm not sure. What is it?"
>   **Sir Patrick**: "Just take your head off... not yours, we'll find one for you to borrow... roll it down the alley, and knock over the pins."

Comment: I'm writing this from the future, where the Harry Potter wiki is no longer accessible.  Any chance you could include a little more detail so we know what you're referring to?

Comment: @Tango - what's this, hassle DVK mid-writing-answer day today? This is the THIRD time people criticize my answer before reading the finalized version!

Comment: Only the third time?  We really were hoping to do more than that - but now that you're on to us, there's no point to it!

Comment: @TangoOversway - Conspiratio Obliviato!

Comment: I'm writing this from the present, where we all acknowledge the worthlessness of the Harry Potter wiki. Any chance you could quote from more trustworthy sources?

Comment: @ibid - what, and lose my hypocrisy points? :)

Comment: Are these from the video games or something?

Answer (score 4):

#### Ghosts likely are able to physically interact.

Ghosts likely can physically interact with each other, since they waltz at Nearly Headless Nick’s
Deathday party.

> “It was an incredible sight. The dungeon was full of hundreds of pearly-white, translucent people, mostly drifting around a crowded dance floor, waltzing to the dreadful, quavering sound of thirty musical saws, played by an orchestra on a black-draped platform.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 8 (The Deathday Party)*</sup></sub>

Waltzing typically requires a certain amount of physical contact, so presumably ghosts can indeed physically interact with each other.

Comment: I don't know why I'm only seeing this answer now. Speaking as a well experienced ballroom dancer, yes, waltzing does typically require physical contact, but it's not hard to find ways to waltz without contact. I have used no-contact ballroom dances in showcase routines I have done myself.